# How do I close this file writer? (Java, Bukkit)

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

```
try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("plugins/TestMessage/messages.txt", true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Hey guys, I know this may sound noobish but how do I close this FileWriter. The code is in java. I have an `onDisable()` method that gets called when the server is stopped but when I put `fw.close();` It says `fw cannot be resolved`. Please help!

The relevant section of the code is

```
public class MAIN extends JavaPlugin{{
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("plugins/TestMessage/messages.txt", true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public void onEnable(){
        Logger.getLogger("Minecraft").info("MessageBroadcaster made by cheeseballs500 aka weakwizardsucks2");
    }

    public void onDisable(){
        fw.close();//fw cannot be resolved
    }
```

EDIT: Fixed :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
public class MAIN extends JavaPlugin{
public MAIN() {
    try {
        this.fw = new FileWriter("plugins/TestMessage/messages.txt", true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}

FileWriter fw = null;

public void onEnable(){
    Logger.getLogger("Minecraft").info("MessageBroadcaster made by cheeseballs500 aka weakwizardsucks2");
}

public void onDisable(){
    try {
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//fw cannot be resolved
}
}
```

Comment: I get `Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor` error with the red underline under `new FileWriter("plugins/TestMessage/messages.txt", true);`

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the `FileWriter` outside of any methods, then setting it to something in your `onEnable()`... Here's an example:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{{
    FileWriter fw;//create the variable

    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        try{
            fw = new FileWriter(this.getDataFolder() + "/messages.txt", true); //assign the variable to a value, and put the file in your plugin's folder
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable(){
        try{ //try-catch just incase
            fw.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Line 7 should actually be:
fw = new FileWriter(this.getDataFolder() + "/messages.txt", true); //assign the variable to a value, and put the file in your plugin's folder